# How can I set preference for routes?

Tags: angular, angular4-router

I have multiple `app.routing.ts` files in my Angular 4 application. Is there any way I can set a preference for routes from one file over other?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplishing with multiple app.routing.ts files? Normally an app would have one app.routing.ts file for its main application routes and then additional routing modules for feature routes such as product.routing.ts.

Comment: So I have this one Angular4 App in which I am importing other Angular4 Apps as Packages from my Pvt. NPM registry. The apps have there own `app.routing.ts` files. I am importing these Apps by adding them as `@imports` to my `app.module .ts` I have specific routing for my main app as well. So what's happening is when I am trying to access a `URL` the component attached to that particular URL is getting overridden by the routes( corresponding components) from my other imported apps routes.

Answer (score 0):

Routes are processed in the order in which they are pulled into the app.module.

When accessing a route, the first match in that order wins.

So to prefer some routes over others that are similar, configure the preferred routes at the top of the list.

For example:

```
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    ProductModule,
    UserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
```

In the above example, all of the ProductModule routes will be "preferred" over the UserModule routes and all of the UserModule routes will be "preferred" over any AppRoutingModule routes.

I have more information about routing ordering here: https://blogs.msmvps.com/deborahk/angular-route-ordering/

Comment: Thank you for answering. But my route files are in a different App which I am importing as a dependency. So it is overlapping with the current routes.